# $_POST data not being passed to database

Tags: php, laravel-4

y'all, I'm making a simple sign-up/registration form and then submitting it to my (localhost) database. The main problem that I am having is that I can't get the data is actually get passed to my database. I am using Laravel 4 to handle the backend, but I am fairly new to it, so I'm sure there is an obvious mistake that I am making, but I can't seem to see it.

Here is the form that I have created using Twitter Bootstrap. There is nothing wrong with the 
action = "/adding_to_table" route call.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link class="cssdeck" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" class="cssdeck">
</head>
<body>
<div class="" id="loginModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <!--<h3>Have an Account?</h3>-->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="well">
            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active in" id="login">
                    <form method="" action='/adding_to_table' class="form-horizontal">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div id="legend">
                                <legend class="">Create Your Account</legend>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Username -->
                                <label class="control-label"  for="firstname">First Name</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="firstname" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Username -->
                                <label class="control-label"  for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="lastname" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Username -->
                                <label class="control-label"  for="email">E-mail</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" id="e_mail" name="email" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Username -->
                                <label class="control-label"  for="username">Username</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Password-->
                                <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Button -->
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
<html>
```

Now, here is the file that is supposed to be taking care of putting the data in the database:

```
DB::table('user_info')->insert(
        array("First_name" => Input::get('first_name'),
              "Last_name" => Input::get("last_name"),
              "E-mail" => Input::get("e_mail"),
              "Username" => Input::get("username"),
              "Password" => Input::get("password")
            )
        );

    echo "Successfully entered user information into data table";
```

Whenever I fill out my form and hit submit, I get the "Whoops, looks like something went wrong" error from Laravel and I'm not quite sure why. Any help that y'all can give would be much appreciated!

Comment: `method=""` - try using a valid value for that attribute

Comment: You don't have `$_POST` data. You have `$_GET` data.

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting the id's of your form elements instead of the names. Try using the `name` attribute:

```
DB::table('user_info')->insert(
        array("First_name" => Input::get('firstname'),
              "Last_name" => Input::get("lastname"),
              "E-mail" => Input::get("email"),
              "Username" => Input::get("username"),
              "Password" => Input::get("password")
            )
        );
```

if you use `method="POST"` then try:

```
DB::table('user_info')->insert(
        array("First_name" => Input::post('firstname'),
              "Last_name" => Input::post("lastname"),
              "E-mail" => Input::post("email"),
              "Username" => Input::post("username"),
              "Password" => Input::post("password")
            )
        );
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed everything that you suggested and it is still not working. However, when I remove the POST from the action field and then comment out the code to submit to the database and replace it with a simple print statement, when I hit submit everything works fine...

Comment: Check if the fields names in the table are matching the names you use in your script ('First_name', 'Last_name', 'E-mail' etc). Also check that you are using the correct table name.

Comment: You could also turn on error details by setting the debug option in your app/config/app.php file to true